# Haskell 'let' implementation

Tags: haskell, happy

Reading Haskell.Happy documentation and reached the implementation of 'let' operator

```
 Exp : let var '=' Exp in Exp              { \p -> $6 (($2,$4 p):p) }
```

docs say it's "a function that takes an environment of variable values, and returns the computed value of the expression:"

can't understand the actual meaning of the syntax, how are these constructions called in Haskell?

Edit: i mean these

```
\p -> $6 (($2,$4 p):p)
```

Comment: Curiously, if you don't know Haskell then why are you learning happy?

Answer (score 5):

A `let` expression in ML-like languages (such as Haskell) just introduces a local variable binding:

```
magnitude x y =
  let xs = x * x in
  let ys = y * y in
  sqrt (xs + ys)
```

The Happy docs are talking about implementing a parser for a hypothetical ML-like language. The `$n` variables in Happy syntax refer to the indices of the things that matched in the current rule:

```
let var '=' Exp in Exp
1   2   3   4   5  6
```

The expression in the curly braces is the code to generate when that rule matches.

So `\p -> $6 (($2,$4 p):p)` gives you a lambda which takes a variable environment `p`, which is a list of pairs of names and values. The body of the lambda consists of the second expression parsed (`$6`) evaluated in `p`, plus the association between the name (`$2`) and the value resulting from evaluating the first expression parsed (`$4`) in the current environment (`$4 p`).

Comment: where does the syntax for $4 p, ($2, $4 p) and ():p come from?

Comment: Happy has it's own special non-Haskell syntax

Comment: They refer to the 2nd, 4th, and 6th values in the pattern.  For example `Exp : let var '=' Exp in Exp` the `let` is `$1`, `=` is `$2 etc.  This means `$6 (($2,$4 p):p)` evaluates to `{2nd exp} ( ({var}, {1st exp} p) : p)`.  Notice the normal Haskell function application of the first expression to the variable `p` and the list cons syntax `:`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I know about values in the pattern, but couldn't understand the logic behind {2nd exp} applied to (({var}, {1st exp} applied to p):p). is that 2nd exp applied to tupple? how is it called in haskell?

Comment: The 2nd expression, `$6` is being applied to the list `someElem : p` where `someElem` is actually a tuple of `$2` and `$4 p` (application of `$4` to `p`).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, an environment `p` such as `[("x",4),("y",5)]` defines the values for variables `x` and `y`. When you evaluate an expression which can involve such variables, the result depends on `p`. This is represented by the `\p -> ...`.

For instance, we could expect something like

```
Exp + Exp    { \p -> $1 p + $2 p }
```

expressing the facts that both terms are evaluated using the same variable values as defined by `p`.

Now, `let` is peculiar because it defines a new variable, giving a value to it. To express this fact, we need to change `p` augmenting it with the new association.

```
let var =  Exp in Exp
$1  $2  $3 $4  $5 $6
```

Given `p`, the value of $4 is simply `$4 p` as we did in the previous sum example (we are assuming that `var` is not visible in $4, that is, we do not allow `var` to be recursively defined). Write

```
value_of_$4 = $4 p
```

However, the value of $6 is not `$6 p` since $6 must "see" the newly defined `var`. So we write

```
value_of_$6 = $6 (p augmented with the association <<var = value_of_$4>>)
```

that is

```
value_of_$6 = $6 ( ($2,value_of_$4) : p )
```

that is

```
value_of_$6 = $6 ( ($2, $4 p) : p )
```

So we end up with

```
let var =  Exp in Exp    { \p -> $6 ( ($2, $4 p) : p ) }
$1  $2  $3 $4  $5 $6
```